# Old French Cipher w/ Text Hidden In Drawing

Tags: cryptanalysis, reference-request, history, steganography

I'm trying to find a cipher challenge I saw a few years back, it was an old drawing (I think 1800's or earlier) with clouds and stars on it and French text was hidden in the image.

Does anyone happen to know the name of this drawing/cipher I'm talking about?

Comment: While I'm not convinced that this is a particularly good question for this site, I'd like to note that this is _not_ an open-ended request for recommendations. The OP has a specific picture in mind, and they're trying to find it, not just something similar. Per fairly well established consensus (see e.g. [here](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919/when-are-reference-requests-actually-on-topic-here)), _specific_ reference requests are on-topic, and should not be closed as "requests for recommendations".

Comment: (That said, if this question keeps getting a lot of really bad answers, I could see an argument for _maybe_ closing it on that basis. But one is not a lot.)